# How can JWE support an integrity check given that it uses a public key to encrypt the message?

Tags: encryption, public-key, integrity, jwt, jwe

As far as I know JWE (JSON Web Encryption) supports both integrity and confidentiality. I agree about the confedintiality because only the recepient with a private key can decrypt a message. What about the integrity? Given that the Content encryption key is encrypted using a public key, anyone (who knows the public key) can generate JWE and receipent won’t know for sure whether its coming from the specific sender.

Can a sender somehow sign the JWE using its own private key (note that this another key pair) so that the recipient can verify the integrity?

Comment: To answer my question it is possible to nest JWS and JWE which will provide both confidentiality and integrity.

Comment: Beware that signatures can be replaced by other signatures. In other words, an adversary with a *trusted* key pair can replace the signature or put a signature on another document with impunity. So it is important if you encrypt-then-sign to only trust one key or a limited set of keys...

Comment: @AbzalSerekov You are allowed to answer your own question.  And you should, just ensure that you add a reference for it.

Answer (score 1):

In short: JWE ensures confidentiality, while Nested JWS (i.e. in JWE) ensures both integrity and confidentiality (the signature is inside the confidential token).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).